# How to require characters after domain name and slash of a url?

Tags: regex, url

This is the regex I've come up with:

```
^(https:\/\/|http:\/\/)?(www.)?example\.com
```

It will match everything from example.com even this address: `https://www.example.com/`

I want the regex to match any url with something after the domain like: `https://www.example.com/testing/proof.php`

It shouldn't match on a url looking like this: `https://www.example.com/`.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match extra content after `example.com` you should add something like `.+` to force content after this string:

```
^(https:\/\/|http:\/\/)?(www.)?example\.com\/.+
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Had no idea that .+ did that

Comment: If you want to do some tests with regex, try this page https://regex101.com/,  it helps me a lot!

Comment: was actually using that tool :) i'm just not that familiar with it

Answer (score 2):

dloeda's answer misses a real opportunity to show some best practices.  Consider all of these refinements:

- the use of verbose "alternatives" (http|https) can be condensed to improve pattern efficiency and brevity.  Futhermore, when alternatives are necessary, always write the shortest potential mismatches first for highest efficiency.
- changing the pattern delimiters from `/` to `~` means `/`'s don't need to be escaped between the delimiters, this improves pattern brevity and readability.
- using a "quantifier" of 3 on `w` and 2 on `/` instead of `www` and `//` (respectively) is a personal choice about readability.  Typing out the repeated characters will actually reduce the pattern length.  The efficiency/accuracy will be the same.
- the dot that follows `www` is not escaped, so it can match any character instead of the intended/literal dot.  Correcting this improves pattern accuracy.
- depending on the language and function that you are implementing this regex pattern in, using capture groups instead of non-capture groups means unnecessary output bloat.  Using non-capture groups does decrease pattern brevity, but it may conserve memory.
- the pattern uses a very literal `example.com` string in the pattern, but this will not serve you well if you are matching different domains.  Writing a non-literal domain expression will improve pattern suitability/flexibility.

> Here is my suggested pattern: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wpTsHf/1))
>
> `~^(?:https?:/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?[^/]+/(?!/).+~`

See these self-explanatory test cases:

```
https://www.pass.com/passing/pass.php
https://www.fail.com/
www.pass.com/pass.php
www.fail.com/
http://fail.com/
http://pass.com/passy-passerson
pass.com/pass.csv
fail.com
```

Improvements:

- Changed pattern delimiters from `/` to `~`.
- Replaced verbose alternatives expression with optional `s`.
- Used non-capturing groups.
- Used quantifier on `w` and `/`.
- Escaped dot after `w{3}`
- Match domain string using "negated character class".
- After matching the domain string followed by `/`, inserted a negative lookahead for a second `/` to ensure that the pattern does not incorrectly match the two slashes that come before the domain.

---

If you are only going to be matching a single domain, then you can use a literal domain expression to make my pattern more readable, but it actually works less efficiently: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKn2rB/2))

`~^(?:https?:/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?example\.com/.+~`

---

If you apply these best practices when you writing regex patterns, you will find your work will be a much higher quality versus simply being "correct".  I hope you found this post educational (and that I didn't waste my time typing this all out).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, although mickmackusa explains it much better than I ever will:

```
(http)s?:\/\/(www.)?example.com\/(.+)
```